# Inequality with cosine and sine

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

Let $A:=f^2+g^2$, where $f,g$ are functions of $x$ such that
$$f'=(c-1)(f\cos(x)\sin(x)+g\sin^2(x)),$$
$$g'=-(c-1)(f\cos^2(x)+g\cos(x)\sin(x)),$$

for some constant $c$.
(Note: $f'\cos(x)+g'\sin(x)=0$)

> How do I show that $A'\leq4|c-1|A?$

I see that
\begin{align}
A'&=2ff'+2gg'\\
&=2(c-1)\left(f^2\cos(x)\sin(x)+fg\sin^2(x)-fg\cos^2(x)-g^2\cos(x)\sin(x)\right)\\
&=2(c-1)(f\cos(x)+g\sin(x))(f\sin(x)-g\cos(x)).
\end{align}
But how does the desired inequality follow?

Comment: Cauchy-Schwartz' inequality tells you that $|a f + b g|\le\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sqrt{f^2+g^2}$.

Comment: @Gribouillis So then I obtain $|A'|\leq2\sqrt{f'^2+g'^2}\sqrt{A}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cauchy-Schwartz' inequality tells you that
$$
|a f + b g| \le \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}\sqrt{f^2+ g^2}
$$
Starting from your result, we obtain
$$
A^\prime\le |A^\prime|\le 2 |c-1|1.\sqrt{f^2+g^2}1.\sqrt{f^2+g^2} = 2 |c-1|A
$$

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the second to last equation to find via trigonometric theorems for the double angle $$A'=(c-1)((f^2-g^2)\sin(2x)-2fg\cos(2x))$$ then using that $$(f^2-g^2)^2+(2fg)^2=(f^2+g^2)^2=A^2$$ like in the construction of Pythagorean triples you even get
$$
A'\le |c-1|A
$$